# How can I reload a facebook page?

Tags: facebook

How can I reload a facebook page ?

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        /*var host = '<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.com&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=90&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:120px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
        $(".like_frame").append(host);*/

        $appdomain = 'http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=263130783727234&sk=app_263130783727234';
        $(".likebtn").attr("href",$appdomain);
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
                function(response) {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
        );

    });
</script>

<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=appid&sk=app" width="450" height="80" class="likebtn"/>
```

As I click on the like button, I need to reload the facebook page.However, the above code redirects me to http://www.facebook.com/insights/?sk=po_263130783727234..
How do I reload my facebook page ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`top.location.href = '<YOUR TAB URL>';`

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```